# Cell Value Accessing Of Telerik RadGrid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to loop through all the columns of Telerik RadGrid and store the value in the SQL DataBase . I have tried this approach but the value i am getting is '&nbsp' for every column .
Any Little help will be appreciated as i am new to asp.net

```
   for (int i = 0; i < this.RadGridDetails.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3,col4) " +
                         "values('" + this.RadGridDetails.Items[i].Cells[0].Text.Trim().ToString() + "','" + this.RadGridDetails.Items[i].Cells[1].Text + "',case when '" + this.RadGridDetails.Items[i].Cells[2].Text + "' = 'Block' then 0 else 1 end " +
                         ",'" + this.t1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ) ", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
  foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridDetails.MasterTableView.Items)
          {
                    new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3,col4) " +
                     "values('" + item[ColumnUniqueName1].Text + "','" + item[ColumnUniqueName2].Text +  "',case when '" + item[ColumnUniqueName3].Text + "' = 'Block' then 0 else 1 end " +
                     ",'" + this.t1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ) ", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
```

and of course declare in each column its UniqueName